# Question using distinct and grouping on WIndows Virtual Desktop session statistics

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need some help creating a Kusto query for filtering and grouping Windows Virtual Desktop statistics.

**What I need:** A chart that shows me the amount of total sessions of users logged in to a WVD Host Pool.

**Data available:** WVD logs this info every x seconds to log analytics for each host. But that interval is not exactly "every x seconds", but at least once every 3 minutes.

So I made this query for now:

```
WVDAgentHealthStatus 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(3m) 
| project SessionHostName, TimeGenerated, ActiveSessions, InactiveSessions, Totalsessions=(toint(ActiveSessions) + toint(InactiveSessions))
```

That makes results like this:
[image]

As you can see, some hosts are reported twice, some three times.

**I need help with:**
How to make this query usable in a chart, so that it shows "the amount of sessions per host" in steps of every 3 minutes, but the chart should show this data for the last 8 hours.

I guess "where TimeGenerated" has to be "> ago(8h)", but it needs to group the data in sets of 3 minutes, then get distinct data per host.

I have no idea how to do this. I'm not that good in Kusto. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hi Mbrouwer88, does the answer below help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`summarize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) operator:

```
WVDAgentHealthStatus 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(8h) 
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, ActiveSessions) by bin(TimeGenerated, 3m), SessionHostName
```

Comment: Hi, ok this groups the data in "windows of 3 minutes", but it still contains duplicate data.
Every Sessionhost reports it's amount of sessions every x seconds. By using your example, sessions are counted double.

As seen in my example, in the timespam of 3 minutes a host might report it's amount of sessions 2 or even 3 three times. The query should sum(ActiveSessions) per "distinct" SessionHostName.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Getting closer. The problem still is that a host reports it's amount of sessions every x seconds. In the set timespan of 3 minutes, it might report once, twice, or more times. With your query above, that is being summed up for each host.    For example, Host A has 3 active sessions in reality. But it logs that amount 2 times within 3 minutes to the logging. Your query shows that there a 6 sessions (2x3), but in fact it's only 3.     How to "filter out the double rows"? See my screenshot in the original post. Host R and U reported 2 times, but host X reported three times.

Comment: I see. How would you like to choose which value to report in your query? Suppose that Host A reports 2 sessions, then 3 sessions, within the same 3-minute window. Do you want to report 2? Or 3? Or always the latest? Once you provide the exact requirement, I'll be able to adjust the query accordingly.

Comment: Hi Slavik, it should only report the latest record per host within those 3 minutes. This way, I can build a chart showing the amount of sessions per host per x minutes. I can compare that with cpu and ram usage to calculate how busy the avd farm is.

Comment: No problem. I've updated the answer accordingly, and am now using arg_max.